# Applying QGraphicsDropShadowEffect more than once crashes the app

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have to apply shadow effect on `QPushButton` based on some condition. I have to remove shadow effect, if  some condition is false and add it again, if the condition becomes true. I am trying to use the following code, but the program crashes.

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(1);
effect->setOffset(2,2);
ui->btnAdd->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
ui->btnAdd->setGraphicsEffect(NULL); //remove effect
ui->btnAdd->setGraphicsEffect(effect); //add again
```

What is wrong with this code? Is there any other method to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in the Qt documentation about `setGraphicsEffect` :

> Sets effect as the widget's effect. If there already is an effect
>   installed on this widget, QWidget will delete the existing effect
>   before installing the new effect.

So when this line is run :

```
ui->btnAdd->setGraphicsEffect(NULL); //remove effect
```

`effect` actually gets deleted. So you should make a new instance of the effect each time you want to set it.